# 301 URL Forwarding with HTACCESS or PHP

Tags: mod-rewrite

Just curious if anyone can help me on this HTACCESS issue.

I have these OLD URLS that need to get forwarded properly.

**Previous structure**

domain.com/Canada/Accounting

domain.com/Canada/Trades

domain.com/Canada/Sales

**Proper structure**

CATEGORY - /jobs/accounting-jobs

LOCATION - /jobs/jobs-kelowna

TOGETHER - /jobs/accounting-jobs-kelowna

**Domain Structure**

domain.com/jobs/*[category]*-jobs-*[location]*

Is this possible, either by HTACCES or PHP...just don't want these 404'ed pages.
I have 86+ to do, if there is a good way to forward these. 
This is what I have, but i'm unable to successfully forward the bad-urls properly.

**OLD**

```
/browse
/Toronto/
/Canada/Administrative
/Vancouver/
/Canada/Trades
/Calgary/
/Canada/Hospitality
```

This is my HTACCESS right now.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    #
    # Trailing slash check
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]


    #
    # PAGES
    RewriteRule ^add-job/?$     /add-job.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^jobs/?$        /results.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^sitemap/?$     /sitemap.php [L]

    #
    # SEARCH
    # CATEGORY - accounting-jobs
    # LOCATION -            jobs-kelowna
    # TOGETHER - accounting-jobs-kelowna
    RewriteRule ^jobs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)?$    results.php?whatwhere=$1&page=$2
    RewriteRule ^jobs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$   results.php?whatwhere=$1&page=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 301 redirect your pages you can do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ /jobs/$2-jobs-$1 [R=301,L]
```

This only addresses the urls from your previous structure (the combinations, you have not shown any previous urls with just location or category) but note that `Canada` will stay `Canada`, it does not become `canada`. You can change everything to lower case using rewrite as well.

You also have to take care that you don't rewrite any of the current urls but without more information, this should do it.

**Edit:** For the location-only urls you could use a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/$ /jobs/jobs-$1 [R=301,L]
```

Again, you need to look out that your rewrite rule does not interfere with your current urls. If that is the case, you would need to redirect every old url manually.

For lower-case new urls, you should search SO, there are some questions with good answers about converting a mized-case variable to lower-case.

Comment: Hey, I added some more examples, is it possible you could take another look... what you sent didn't quite turn out.... possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `mod_rewrite`, you can add these lines to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Canada/Accounting$ /jobs/accounting-jobs [R,L]
```

However, it's not clear from your question exactly what you want mapped. Are the 3 previous URLs supposed to redirect to the 3 new ones? They don't seem to be equivalent.

Comment: Yes that would work, but I have 86 to do, wondering if there is an easier option...

Comment: You need to give more information. Show several example old URLs and what they should map to.

Comment: I have added some more examples / content... are you able to take another look?